How important are purely imaginary finite action solutions for first-order instanton contributions?
I am working on a physics problem where I have to calculate instanton contributions for a non-relativistic Hamiltonian
$$H=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}g^2x^6 \tag 1$$
for negative coupling. Now, it is obvious that there are four non-trivial saddles for the partition function, two of which are purely real while the other two are purely imaginary values (the real and imaginary ones have actions $\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{4g}$ respectively). And right here is where my problem starts, as I do not know what to make of those imaginary values and how and even IF I should incorporate them in the calculation, as almost all similar problems I have looked at only have potentials with purely real valued finite action solutions (e.g. anharmonic quartic oscillator, double well potential etc.).
Details:
I already calculated the perturbative series for positive couplings and now I am looking for the imaginary part of my groundstate energy using the large beta limit of the partition function:
$$E_0=\lim\limits_{\beta\rightarrow \infty}\left(-\frac{1}{\beta}\ln\, tr\, e^{-\beta H}\right) \quad .\tag 2$$
We know
$$tr \, e^{-\beta H}= \int\limits_{q\left(-\frac{\beta}{2}\right)=q\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}[\mathrm dq(t)]\, e^{-S(q)} \quad , \tag 3$$
where
$$S(q)=\int\limits_{-\frac{\beta}{2}}^{\frac{\beta}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2} \dot{q}^2+\frac{1}{2}q^2+\frac{1}{6}g^2q^6\right)\,\mathrm dt \quad . \tag 4$$
We want to rotate our contour in the functional $q(t)$ space (while changing $g^2$ from positive to negative) in such a way that $\mathrm{Re}\,[\dot{q}^2]>0$ and $\mathrm{Re}\,[g^2q^6]>0$ and integrate over paths that satisfy these relations. So by $q(t) \rightarrow q(t)e^{-i\theta}$ we find that $\frac{\pi}{4}<\theta < \frac{\pi}{6}$.
I already know, that my solutions should have a structure like
$$\mathrm{Im} \, E_0 \sim \frac{C}{\sqrt{g}}e^{-a/g}\quad . \tag 5$$
The exponential term is just the solution of the classical action with the classical path. The term $c/g$ arises from the contributions of the Gaussian integration over the fluctuation terms. Now this is the difficult part: I do not know how all the saddles contribute to the terms $a$ (classical action at $g=1$) and to the Gaussian approximation of the integrals. If the purely imaginary saddles weren't here it would be relatively easy but I don't know how to account for them or which arguments to use if I don't have to account for them.

Are you following a reference? Which page?

Comment to the post (v5): The interval should presumably be $\frac{\pi}{12}<\theta < \frac{\pi}{4}$.

OP wants to replace the quartic potential $V_{\rm int}(q)=\frac{g}{4}q^4$ in Refs. 1-2 with a sextic potential
$$V_{\rm int}(q)=\frac{g}{6}q^6.\tag{A}$$
The Euclidean Lagrangian is
$$\begin{align}L_E~=~&\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2+V(q), \cr
V(q)~=~&V_2(q)+V_{\rm int}(q),\cr
 V_2(q)~=~&\frac{1}{2}q^2, \cr
 q(T)~=~&q(0), \qquad T~\equiv~\beta. \end{align} \tag{B}$$
The Euclidean action is
$$ S_E~=~\int_{[0,T]}\!dt~L_E.\tag{C}$$
The partition function is
$$Z(g)~=~\int_{q(0)=q(T)}^{\dot{q}(0)=\dot{q}(T)}\!{\cal D}q ~\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S_E \right\}.\tag{D}$$
$q:[0,T]\to\mathbb{C}$ is a path from the worldline$^1$ to the complex plane. For ${\rm Re}(g)>0$ we assume that $q(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ is integrated along the real axis. To analytically continue $Z(g)$ ($\overline{Z(g)}$) into the complex $g$-plane, we should assume that the integration coutours $C_{\pm}(t)$ are in exponentially decaying sectors
$$ {\rm Re}[gq^6(t)]~>~0\quad\text{and}\quad {\rm Re}[\dot{q}^2(t)]~>~0,\tag{E}$$
i.e. that the $\theta$ angle of $C_{\pm}(t)$ satisfies
$$  \theta ~\in~]-\frac{\pi}{12},\frac{\pi}{12}[ \quad \text{for}\quad {\rm Re}(g)~>~0, \tag{F}$$
and
$$\theta ~\in~]-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{12}[~\cup~]\frac{\pi}{12},\frac{\pi}{4}[ \quad \text{for}\quad {\rm Re}(g)~<~0.  \tag{G}$$
Let us from now on focus on the case $g=-|g|<0$. The potential $V$ has 4 constant stationary points
$$ q_{\rm cl}~=~\sqrt[4]{-1/g}~\propto~\pm 1,\pm i, \tag{H}$$
i.e. 2 real and 2 imaginary constant stationary points, as OP mentions. Instantons have conserved energy given by
$$E~=~\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2-V(q). \tag{I}$$
Looking at the $-V$ potential we expect the instantons that are close to the 2 real (imaginary) constant stationary points (say, with small kinetic energy) to have $E<0$ ($E>0$), respectively. In the large $T\equiv\beta$ limit/low temperature limit, we can therefore ignore the 2 imaginary constant stationary points, cf. OP's question.
References:

J. Zinn-Justin, QFT & Critical Phenomena, 2002; Chapter 39 + Fig. 39.1.

M. Marino, Instantons and large
$N$; Chapter 2 + Fig. 8.



$^1$ One can also consider the toymodel without Euclidean time in Refs. 1-2, i.e. the worldline is replaced by a worldpoint. Again the  quartic potential is replaced with the sextic potential. The imaginary part ${\rm Im}Z(g)$ is calculated from the integration contour $C_+-C_-$. Using the method of steepest descent one sees that only the real (and not the imaginary) stationary points contribute. This is because the imaginary stationary points are trapped behind anti-Stokes curves.
